# RecordsAffected condition in data reader

Tags: c#, ado.net

Here is my code:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from table1 where col1 = 'YES'", conn);
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
SqlDataReader dr = command7.ExecuteReader();

if (dr.RecordsAffected>0)
{

}
```

the select query passes the condition for few values, but still it bypasses the if condition.

Comment: Note that `See the documentation` is an *excellent* first step no matter what problem you are having.

Answer (score 2):

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.recordsaffected?view=netframework-4.8). A select statement does not affect any rows, it does not insert or delete or update any rows. So the value will always be 0 with a select. If you want to check if there are records returned use [`HasRows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows?view=netframework-4.8) instead.

```
using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from table1 where col1 = 'YES'", conn))
{
  command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  using(SqlDataReader dr = command7.ExecuteReader()) {
    if (dr.HasRows) {

    }
  }
}
```

Side notes:

- Wrap your instances where the type implements `IDisposable` in a `using` block to ensure that the unmanaged resources are always released.
- If you have input that you want to use in your statements then use parameters instead of hard coding values. It is not clear if that is the case here so I left the statement as is.
- If you intend to read the data back in the reader you should not use `*`, instead specify the column names in the SELECT. This could protect your code from changes in the schema like the order that columns are defined in the table. Example: `SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table...`.